# Preventing Render-Blocking in Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I currently have an issue with a client's website that uses Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 with LESS. The technical lead at my client has flagged that Google Pagespeed Insights is showing a red flag against several of the CSS files in the site causing render blocking issues:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ukessays.com%2Fservices%2Fessay-writing-service.php&tab=mobile

However, the above the fold content on the majority of pages contains almost all of the CSS elements used in the site so the idea of "in-lining" all of the CSS to render the above the fold content seems completely ridiculous. To make things worse the most important pages in the site have the lowest speed scores:

`http://www.ukessays.com/services/essay-writing-service.php : 71/100`

vs

`http://www.ukessays.com/essay-help/referencing/ : 77/100`

As the website was re-built using Twitter Bootstrap to make it more responsive I'm left looking a bit of an idiot that it now scores less than the previous non-responsive website. The fact that the CSS is compiled using LESS has effective prevented us from implementing any dynamic solution to the problem server-side

Has anyone come across this problem and if so can anyone recommend a simple fix / plugin that could solve this issue?

The only solution we have so far is to take the entire of the above the fold content, from the H! tag of "essay writing service" down to the first call to action and save this is a completely isolated div structure that doesn't flow with the rest of the page.

Comment: See http://www.appneta.com/blog/bootstrap-pagespeed/ for example (For your question the only thing I can't understand is that how a "Compiled CSS" is different from "any other CSS" and what does it have to do with Less at all).

Comment: What I was trying to say is that the whole CSS file is compiled on our local server and uploaded as a single minified file. The suggestions from reading Google's faqs regarding render blocking is that the css needs to be aware of the user's session so that only the relevant css is parsed based on the users viewport. I don;t see how this is possible with a pre-compiled css file such as bootstrap.css. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Fantastic post by AppNeta, probably the only sensible post I've seen on reducing render blocking with Bootstrap. Not able to implement all of their findings but already seeing a score of 89/100 in our page speed experiments.

Comment: The appneta blog post has been moved/deleted. Incase someone is looking for it: http://web.archive.org/web/20170512053430/http://www.appneta.com/blog/bootstrap-pagespeed/

Comment: You the real MVP dinesh!